# Integration involves derivative of delta function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, dirac-delta-distributions, variational-calculus, boundary-terms

This appears in explicitly calculating the path integral of harmonic oscillators:

First note the second functional derivative of classical action is
$$\frac{\delta^2 S[x]}{\delta x(t1)\delta x(t2)}=-m(\frac{d^2}{d t_1^2}+\omega^2)\delta (t_1-t_2)$$
Then expand around the classical path $x_c$ is
\begin{align*}
S[x_c+y]=S[x_c]+\frac{1}{2!}\int dt_1\,dt_2 y(t_1)y(t_2)\frac{\delta^2 S[x]}{\delta x(t1)\delta x(t2)}\\
=S[x_c]-\frac{m}{2!}\int dt_1\,dt_2 y(t_1)y(t_2)(\frac{d^2}{d t_1^2}+\omega^2)\delta (t_1-t_2)
\end{align*}
Apply the integration by part to the delta function part, I got $$-\frac{m}{2} \int dt_1 y(t_1)\frac{d^2}{d(t_1)^2}y(t_1)$$
while the book gives
$$\frac{m}{2}\int dt_1 (\frac{d y(t_1)}{dt_1})^2.$$

Any suggestions for what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is correct, with one more step you would have got the book result

$$-\frac{m}{2}\int dt_1\,y(t_1)\frac{d^2y(t_1)}{d t_1^2}=-\frac{m}{2}\int dt_1\,\Bigg[\frac{d}{dt_1}\Bigg(y(t_1)\frac{dy(t_1)}{d t_1}\Bigg)-\Bigg(\frac{dy(t_1)}{dt_1}\Bigg)^2\Bigg]=\\=\frac{m}{2}\int dt_1\Bigg(\frac{dy(t_1)}{dt_1}\Bigg)^2$$

Comment: Ohhh, Thank you so much!